# Javascript removing array that have same values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove / delete array elements with the same username and authorID from array but it seems to just remove all of the arrays?

So i was just wondering if anyone knew why this happening or if there would be a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

```js
var arrayInstances = [];

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 1,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 1,
  authorID: 111111,
  username: 'BOB 1',
  isadmin: false,
});

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 1,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 2,
  authorID: 111111,
  username: 'BOB 1',
  isadmin: false,
});

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 3,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 3,
  authorID: 333333,
  username: 'BOB 2',
  isadmin: true,
});

arrayInstances.filter(e => e.authorID == 111111 && e.username == 'BOB 1').forEach(x => console.log(x))
arrayInstances.filter(e => e.authorID == 111111 && e.username == 'BOB 1').forEach(x => arrayInstances.splice(x))
setTimeout(() => console.log(arrayInstances), 5000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reassign the filtered array back to your variable. Also use `!==` to filter the 111111 authorID and BOB 1 username.

```js
let arrayInstances = [];

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 1,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 1,
  authorID: 111111,
  username: 'BOB 1',
  isadmin: false,
});

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 1,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 2,
  authorID: 111111,
  username: 'BOB 1',
  isadmin: false,
});

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 3,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 3,
  authorID: 333333,
  username: 'BOB 2',
  isadmin: true,
});

arrayInstances = arrayInstances.filter((e) => e.authorID !== 111111 && e.username !== 'BOB 1')


setTimeout(() => console.log(arrayInstances), 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it already with the filter, you don't need to splice anything. Just re-assign the filtered array to the same variable if you want it "in-place".

```
var arrayInstances = [];

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 1,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 1,
  authorID: 111111,
  username: 'BOB 1',
  isadmin: false,
});

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 1,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 2,
  authorID: 111111,
  username: 'BOB 1',
  isadmin: false,
});

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 3,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 3,
  authorID: 333333,
  username: 'BOB 2',
  isadmin: true,
});

arrayInstances = arrayInstances.filter(e => e.authorID == 111111 && e.username == 'BOB 1');

console.log(arrayInstances);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom de-duplication function, or use lodash's [`uniqBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy).

Like this:

```js
var arrayInstances = [];

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 1,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 1,
  authorID: 111111,
  username: 'BOB 1',
  isadmin: false,
});

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 1,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 2,
  authorID: 111111,
  username: 'BOB 1',
  isadmin: false,
});

arrayInstances.push({
  id: 3,
  url: "https://likehere.com/#" + 3,
  authorID: 333333,
  username: 'BOB 2',
  isadmin: true,
});

const result = _.uniqBy(arrayInstances, 'authorID');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```